# Python Cannot find file although the error says it exists

Tags: python

I have been trying to load the files in python but somehow I cant do so? any help or suggestions would be really helpful.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Work/a.csv')
type(df)
print df
```

Error shown:

```
File C:/Users/user/Desktop/Work/a.csv does not exist
```

Comment: What does "not' mean?

Comment: The error says it "does **not** exist" - which is it?

Comment: @KenY-N the csv file maybe?

Comment: @JulienBernu where is the not?

Comment: Clearly the file does not exist or is not where you think it is. Locate it and check the full path.

Comment: @JulienSpronck do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How can you be sure that the file exists? Did you check it in the Windows Explorer? Are you sure you're looking at the correct path? Really?

Comment: I just gave you my suggestion: check the full path of the file (in Windows Explorer or using `dir` on the windows command prompt)

Comment: In windows, file paths don't use `/`, but \

Comment: @Matthias I copied it from the windows explorer,from Properties section but  its still not working

Comment: @YotamSalmon Windows can actually handle both.

Comment: There is not much we can do for you. Maybe you can copy `a.csv` to the directory where you are running python and just call `df=pd.read_csv('a.csv')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using windows. Windows directory separator is `\` not `/`
try this way:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Work\\a.csv')
```

or

```
import os
file_path = os.path.sep.join(["C:", "Users", "user", "Desktop", "Work", "a.csv"])
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```